# Где лучше всего хранить видео для приложения

Tags: firebase, видео, mediaplayer, google-cloud

У меня есть приложение на котором мы используем ютубовский плеер, реализованный через WebView. Сейчас нужно перейти на другой плеер. Раньше мы использовали Firebase, но его проблема заключалась в том что там стоял трафик только на 1 ГБ на все видео в месяц. Сейчас хотелось бы найти сервис, где можно хранить видео с неограниченным  трафиком загрузки видео. Если что самое приложение было написано на Flutter.

Comment: Какие объемы трафика у вас? Можно зарегистрировать бесплатный аккаунт aws.amazon.com

Comment: ну мне кажется если одно видео весит 30 мб и юзер смотрит где-то 10 раз в день то 300 мб на одного юзера. А у нас таких пользователей 30к